# On an excel spread sheet how do I sort numeric values from 5 columns in asc order left to right 1 row at a time iterating through all rows

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I have not been able to increment rows for a range of columns and perform a sort on the range for each row, can someone guide me through this please?

Using a Macro or VBA, how do I sort integers from 5 columns in ascending order left to right 1 row at a time iterating through all rows of data (approx. 765 rows).

Each row has 6 columns of data but only the first 5 columns need to be sorted.
Each row has the same amount of columns and data and there are never cells with blank or NULL entries.
Each column in a row contains an integer which is unique for that row.

Each row needs to be sorted independent of the previous or next row and the 6th column in each row must remain with the sorted 5 previous columns.

I haven't been able to figure out how to increment a range of columns in order to perform the sort in each row.  Much appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: How do I reply to you, the web page limits me on the number of characters so i can't show you what I tried.  Basically I ran a Macro sorting each row as I needed, then tried to tweak it to iterate through the rows.  i used some samples from this web site, but could not get it to work...  Can you tell me where/how I can paste what I've tried so far?  Sorry I'm new to the site.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the five columns you want sorted are A through E.  This macro loops through each column (entire column) and sorts independently of the adjacent columns.

Try this:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Set rng = Range("A:E")

    For Each col In rng.Columns
        Set rng = Columns(col.Column)

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Cells(1, col.Column), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Data looks like this to start with:

[image]

And will look like this after running the macro:

[image]

Notice that the last column is untouched.

---

****EDIT****

Here is how you can sort rows left to right instead of columns as shown above: (It's sorting Rows A1 thru A10 from column 'A' to Column 'E'

```
Sub Macro2()
    Set Rng = Range("A1:E10")
    col = Rng.Cells(Rng.Count).Column

    Dim lastcol As Integer
    lastcol = Rng.Cells(Rng.Count).Column

    For Each rrow In Rng.Rows
        Set RngB = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rrow.Row, Rng.Column), ActiveSheet.Cells(rrow.Row, lastcol))

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=RngB, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
            .SetRange RngB
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I guess I wasn't specific enough.  Each row retains it's own numbers.  Example: Row 1: 4, 53, 19, 44, 11 - after the sort Row 1:4, 11, 19, 44, 53.  The next row sorts it's own numbers lowest to highest column A through E, on and on down some 765 rows.  There is no mingling between the rows and everything is sorted left to right in the same row before moving to the next row.  Thank you for replying, I appreciate it.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post.  See the last section of code that show how to sort by rows.

Comment: You're awesome Portland Runner, this almost worked!  It sorted the 6th column in with the rest even though I had changed your code above to col= Range("E1").Column...

Comment: Can't, just that one glitch...  with sorting the F column...  Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I miss read your earlier post on my phone.  I updated .setrange line in the code.  Here you can set what ever column (E) you want.

Comment: Wow, Portland Runner, this sort code had an interesting outcome...  I altered your code at the top and set the range to "A1:E767", and set .Header = xlYes - (my headers are "Number 1, Number 2, Number 3, Number 4, Number 5"), then executed.  My numbers are still in their own rows, but in a new column order: "Number 5, Number 3, Number 2, Number 4, Number 1"...  Each row retained their numbers, such as in position A of row 395 I got '52' which was the integer found in position E:395 ("Number 5")... The numbers are not in ascending order, but in the new column order described. :-(  Any clues?

Comment: Ummm, the last row sorted set the order of the columns...  Does that help Portland Runner?  Would it simplify things to designate columns G - K for placement of the sorted integers on each row?

Comment: I had set the key range and sort range incorrectly on the last edit.  The post has been updated.  Please note that the code steps through each row one at a time because you wanted them independent of other columns.  This means that you don't want to change .Header=xlYes because it only see's one row at a time.  If you have a header that you don't want sorted, change your range to "A2:E767" to skip first row.